# PhpStorm doesn't recognize some Laravel components

Tags: laravel, composer-php, phpstorm

I'm new user of Laravel. I'm using it in PhpStorm and it's not working: it doesn't recognize `@yield`, `@extend`, `@if` or `@else` etc.

```
@if (Route::has('login'))
    <div class="top-right links">
        @if (Auth::check())
            <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
        @else
            <a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
            <a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
        @endif
   </div>
@endif
```

[image: screenshort]

Comment: Post the code as text and not as an image.

Comment: blade isn't meant to be interpreted directly by PHP, it's meant to be compiled by Laravel and then interpreted.

Comment: You are using an old version from phpstorm which doesn't recognize those components.

Answer (score 6):

You have two options here which can be combined

### Laravel Plugin for PhpStorm

Go to the plugin pane in PhpStorm and install the [Laravel plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532-laravel-plugin) (not sure it its not already shipped with it)

Restart PhpStorm and activate the Plugin in PhpStorm in the configuration under *Language & Frameworks -> PHP -> Laravel*

## Laravel IDE Helper package

Install the [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package via composer

`$ composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`

For further installation of the package follow the documentation over at the github Repository because its highly depending on your Laravel version.

After your got the plugin and the IDE Helper Package running, use the following commands to generate the IDE helper classes:

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
php artisan ide-helper:meta
```

Answer (score 1):

Go To Phpstorm > Settings > Plugins > Marketplace > search for laravel
and then you will find respective plugins including Blade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use newer PhpStorm version as the one you are currently using is too old.

As far as I remember support for Blade templates was added in **PhpStorm v8** .. and you are using v7.1.3.

Latest version is 2017.3 and can be downloaded from JetBrains website: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/